# Scala Throwable raised inside for comprehension yield block is expecting custom ExceptionHandler

Tags: scala

My function signature is like below

```
def createEntity(json: Json): Either[Throwable, T] = {
 json.as[T] flatMap { data =>
  for {
     a_id <- root.a_id.string.getOption(json).orThrowable("Missing a id")
     b_id <- root.b_id.string.getOption(json).orThrowable("Missing b id")
     data <- getData(b_id)
  } yield { 
      if (checkIfExists(b_id).size > 0) {
        throw new Error(s"Data for $b_id already exists")
      }
      ...
   }
 }
}
```

Now this function is called as part of an `Http` call.

```
 post {
          complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, createEntity(myJson))
      }
```

The problem I am seeing with this is `Throwable` part of `yield` block is not getting returned as `Http response` rather I am getting

`Error during processing of request: 'Data for someID already exists'. Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response. To change default exception handling behavior, provide a custom ExceptionHandler.`

But the other `Throwable` while `json` parsing like `"Missing a id"` , `"Missing b id"` is working fine as `response` .

Comment: Well, that is because the other throwables are not thrown, rather lifted in the `Either` and returned a normal values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for`-comprehension is not a `try`-`catch` block. Unless Either's map/flatMap/foreach would catch (they aren't) exception transparently will get thrown out of each nested function.

If you wanted to do a validation you should have done:

```
def createEntity(json: Json): Either[Throwable, T] = {
  for {
    a_id <- root.a_id.string.getOption(json).orThrowable("Missing a id")
    b_id <- root.b_id.string.getOption(json).orThrowable("Missing b id")
    data <- getData(b_id)
    _ <- Either.cond(checkIfExists(b_id).isEmpty, (), new Error(s"Data for $b_id already exists"))
  } yield { 
    ...
  }
}
```